# Conversion of optional valued expressions to boolean

Tags: swift

This feels very basic. My apologies in advance. But consider the following four variations on the same theme:

```
var q : String? = nil

if let z : String? = q {
    println("q is non-nil")
} else {
    println("q is nil")
}

var zz : String? = nil
if (zz) {
    println("zz is not nil")
} else {
    println("zz is nil")
}

if let z : String? = nil {
    println("nil is non-nil")
} else {
    println("nil is nil")
}

/*
if (nil) {
    println("nil is non-nil")
} else {
    println("nil is nil")
}
*/
```

Naively, I think these should all behave identically. But the output is...

```
q is nil
zz is nil
nil is non-nil
```

If I uncomment the final form, I get...

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:57:5: error: type 'NilType' does not conform to protocol 'LogicValue'
if (nil) {
```

What are the rules that explain when an optional expression can be treated as a boolean, with nil as false and {Some whatever} as true? Why does the third if statement print "nil is not nil" when it seems semantically identical to the others? Why is nil acceptable/convertable-to-LogicValue in an if statement when bound to a variable or in a let expression, but not when presented as a literal?

Comment: The third `if` printing `nil is non-nil` looks very much like a bug in the compiler. Did you report this to Apple?

Comment: (no... i thought i must be missing something. this is my first time playing with swift; when in doubt, i assume i am wrong.)

Comment: As a rule, that's a very smart assumption to make most of the time. Beta-testing is one notable exception from that rule ;-)

Comment: Is there any documentation about what `if let z : String? = q` is supposed to do, as opposed to `if let z = q` which is well documented as returning true and unwrapping q into z if q is non-nil?

Comment: Regarding `if nil` ... an if statement requires a Boolean. nil isn't a Boolean

Comment: What happens if you declare a type (e.g. `String?`) for `nil` in the fourth example? I.e. `if nil : String? {...`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My hunch is, that the third `if` is (and always was) a correct form of optional binding and the type of the rhs `nil` literal just is String??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the third case makes sense. "If let" is testing whether or not the assignment is successful. The normal pattern is:

```
var optional : String?
if let nonOptional : String = optional {
    // the optional could successfully be converted to a non-optional
}
```

You are simply trying to assign nil to an optional, which is indeed possible and valid. Therefore, the "let if" returns true.

It is also common to do the same thing with down-casting assignments

```
var any : AnyObject = "Hello"
if let string = any as? String {
     // Downcast to String was successful
}
```

Finally, it is the Optional type that conforms to being a  `LogicValue` allowing it to be used in an `if` statement. It is **NOT** that the optional returns `nil` and the `nil` is tested. `nil` standing alone cannot be used in an if statement because it does not implement the `LogicValue` protocol and there is no reason for it to do so.

Comment: thanks. but doesn't nil need to conform to the Optional type itself, so wouldn't it then need to implement the LogicValue protocol if Optional does in order to conform? (sorry again if i'm missing something very basic.)

Comment: @SteveWaldman nil does not need to conform to Optional, Optional just needs to define an assignment operator with it

Answer (score 3):

Your `Optional Binding` syntax is incorrect.

it should be `if let z = q {}`

If you must add a type, it should be: `if let z:String = q`

If you do that,

```
if let z : String = nil {
    println("nil is non-nil")
} else {
    println("nil is nil")
}
```

This behaves correctly and prints `nil is nil`.

For the last case,
the expression must be a `bool`. The reason `if q` compiles is that it checks against `nil` for you and still returns a boolean.